# Google Distance Matrix API returning results in incorrect order

Tags: javascript, api, google-distancematrix-api

I'm using the Google Distance Matrix API to return the travel time over different modes of transport. While it works sometimes, it seems that results are not always consistent and are outputted in incorrect order. I'm reading from a CSV of Lat's Longs and have a premium account API key. It'd be nice to perhaps do the whole file at once if possible (about 5,500 entries).

```
var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);//Splits rows
var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
var item=0;
var long;
var lat;
var long2;
var lat2;
var loc1;
var loc2;
var flat;
var flong;
var flat2;
var flong2;
var transport;
var id;
var tcount=0;
for(var count = 0; count<employee_data.length; count++){
    var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
    for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++){
        if(item===0){
            id=cell_data[cell_count];
        }
        else if(item===1){
            lat=cell_data[cell_count];
            flat = parseFloat(lat);     
        }
        else if (item===2){
            long=cell_data[cell_count];
            flong = parseFloat(long);
        }
        else if(item===4){
            lat2=cell_data[cell_count];
            flat2=parseFloat(lat2);
        }
        else if(item===5){
            long2=cell_data[cell_count];
            flong2=parseFloat(long2);
        }
        item++;
        if(item===6){

            loc1 = {lat:flat, lng:flong};
            loc2 = {lat:flat2, lng:flong2};
            if(tcount<100){
                calculateTime(loc1,loc2,id);
            }
            tcount++;
            item=0;
        }
    }
}
function calculateTime(x,y,tcount){         
    var location1 = [x];
    var location2 = [y];
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: location1,
        destinations:location2,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    }, callback);       
}
function callback(response, status) {
    try{
       if (status == 'OK') {          
           var duration;
           var distance;
           var from;
           var origins = response.originAddresses;
           var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
           for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
             var results = response.rows[i].elements;
             for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                 var element = results[j];
                 distance = element.distance.text;
                 duration = element.duration.text;
                 from = origins[i];
                 var to = destinations[j];
             }
         }
         console.log(duration);         
     }
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log('error caught');
    }
}
```